# clickonce dev and prod environment

Tags: clickonce

How do you guys manage a dev and a prod environment with a clickonce project ?
We would like to use only one project for development but then when we deploy to the prod server we want to update the url without having to change in the project properties everytime since this is prone to errors.

Any idea on how to manage this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickonce deployment to multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775202/clickonce-deployment-to-multiple-environments)

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to an issue with my configuration file.

I had:

```
    "includePattern": ".+\\.(md|js)$",
```

instead of

```
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js$",
```